# How to record count from ASP.NET using stored procedure?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, count

I am trying to output the number of depositors which has a total of 5 but when I run the program it outputs only 1. I used stored procedure for this matter. I think something is missing when in the codes below and I don't know. I tried my best to search on the internet.

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        CountAllUsers();
    }
}

protected void CountAllUsers()
{
    using (MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection(constring))
    { 
        mycon.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("countallusers", mycon);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        MySqlDataAdapter adx = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds= new DataSet();
        adx.Fill(ds);

        mycon.Close();

        lblDepositors.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: You don't need a stored-procedure nor do you need to use `DataAdapter` - just run a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableName` query in a `MySqlCommand`.

Comment: @Dai okay will do. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ExecuteScalar` to do the query for counting the number of records. Replace `TABLE_NAME` with your table.

FYI, you don't have to call `mycon.Close();`, as you apply using statement, when it ends, it will dispose the connection automatically.

**Updated**:
Added using block for MySqlCommand for `Disposable` best practice as suggested by @Dai.

```
protected void CountAllUsers()
{
    using (MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection(constring))
    {  
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_NAME", mycon)) 
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            mycon.Open();

            var count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            lblDepositors.Text = count.ToString();
        }       
    }
}
```

[MySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar Method](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand_ExecuteScalar.htm)

> ExecuteScalar method to retrieve a single value (for example, an aggregate value) from a database.

Comment: You should wrap the Command in a using block too.

Comment: Okay, I think it's good to apply MySqlCommand with using block as it is supported with Dispose method and to apply best practice for releasing resources once the process ends. Anyway thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

I already solved. Thanks!

```
protected void CountAllUsers()
    {
        using (MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection(constring))
        {
            
            mycon.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(id) as count from depositors_tbl", mycon);
            MySqlDataAdapter ada = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            DataSet dt = new DataSet();
            ada.SelectCommand = cmd;
            ada.Fill(dt);
            mycon.Close();

            lblDepositors.Text = dt.Tables[0].Rows[0]["count"].ToString();
        }

    }
```

Comment: You don't need to use a `MySqlDataAdapter` - your code is more complicated than it needs to be. Also, `MySqlDataAdapter` doesn't support asynchronous IO.